# Optimize Cypher query on multiple unique labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

In Neo4j, is it faster to run a query against all nodes (AllNodesScan) and then filter on their labels with a WHERE clause, or to run multiple queries with a NodeByLabelScan?

---

To illustrate, I want all nodes that are labeled with one of the labels in label_list:

```
label_list = ['label_1', 'label_2', ...]
```

Which would be faster in an application *(this is pseudo-code)*:

```
for label in label_list:
    run.query("MATCH (n:{label}) return n")
```

or

```
run.query("MATCH (n) WHERE (n:label_1 or n:label_2 or ...)")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Actually, I just realized that the best option might be to run multiple NodeByLabelScan in a single query, with something looking like this:

```
MATCH (a:label_1)
MATCH (b:label_2)
...
UNWIND [a, b ..] as foo
RETURN foo
```

Could someone speak to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be better to run multiple `NodeByLabelScan`s in a single query.

For example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:label_1)
WITH COLLECT(a) AS list
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:label_2)
WITH list + COLLECT(b) AS list
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:label_3)
WITH list + COLLECT(c) AS list
UNWIND list AS n
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

Notes on the query:

- It uses [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match) so that the query can proceed even if a wanted label is not found in the DB.
- It uses multiple [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) steps to avoid [cartesian products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33354771/974731) (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55958278/974731)).
- And it uses [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) so that it can use`DISTINCT` to return distinct nodes (since a node can have multiple labels).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional references!
Interestingly, I tried running a simple ```OPTIONAL MATCH (a:label_1) OPTIONAL MATCH (b:label_2) OPTIONAL MATCH (c:label_3) RETURN a, b, c``` and it is incredibly slow (it does not even return a result),
I do not understand why, is ```a, b, c``` a cartesian product under the hood?